# XBee End device stops responding after network join

Tags: xbee

I have two XBee S2 modules.

First module has freshly uploaded *ZigBee Coordinator API* version 21A7. `PAN ID = 1000`; `AP=2`; the rest has default values.

Second has freshly loaded *ZigBee End Device API* version 29A7. `PAN ID=1000`; `AP=2`; the rest has default values.

While end device is not joined to coordinator, it responds to all AT commands. For example *AT NI* command (`7E 00 04 08 01 4E 49 5F`) returns correct *AT Command Response*.

After turning on coordinator, end device correctly joins coordinator's network, but stops responding to local (and transmitting remote) AT commands.

Despite this non-functionality end device is correctly responding to remote AT commands from coordinator.

Do you have some idea please?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the end device might be sleeping once it's joined to the coordinator.  You can't send serial data to it while it's sleeping, and may need to monitor the `CTS` signal coming from the XBee.  Or, make use of the "sleep request" pin on the end device for the host to signal the XBee module to wake up.

If you don't have low power requirements on your project, I'd recommend using a "router" device configuration instead of a sleepy end device.  Routers on the network form a mesh for transferring information, and you don't have to worry about multiple issues related to sleeping (host can't send serial data to sleeping end device, remote devices can only have one outstanding frame pending for a sleeping device, etc.)